# Any selector for checking if an attribute name starts with a value?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know you can select the elements if the attribute exists

```
[data-value] { /* rules */ }
```

Or that its values starts with some val

```
[data-value^="foo"] { /* rules */ }
```

But, can I check if any elements contain contains a prefixed attribute?

```
[^data-] { /* something like it? /*}
```

This question came when I was trying to query all attributes of the page that has a prefixed aria atrittube. eg. aria-hidden, aria-live...

Comment: So you want to select any element that has an `aria-*` attribute?

Comment: The words property and attribute are not interchangeable. Please don't use one word to mean the other.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, I changed to avoid confusion

Comment: @dippas gave you the answer for properties, but I don't think you can do a wildcard select for attributes.

Comment: @Shomz well, that's the question.

Comment: I would suggest changing your question to "attribute name" instead, as it's confusing people who think you want the check the value of the attribute instead

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do what you want with just CSS selectors, you would have to specify each attribute that you want to include. For example:

```
[aria-hidden], [aria-live]
{
}
```

It would be possible however to do something with javascript, so you may want to look into that if it's an option for you.

Comment: For `aria-` at least, it's not hard to have [an exhaustive list](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#state_prop_def)